# Trying to enumerate through NSFetchedResultsControllers

Tags: objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller, enumeration

I have 4 tableviews all with their own NSFetchedResultsController

At one point I'm trying to reset/reload them all.. like so

```
fetchedResultsControllerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:__fetchedResultsController1, __fetchedResultsController2, __fetchedResultsController3, __fetchedResultsController4, nil];


for (NSFetchedResultsController __strong *frc in fetchedResultsControllerArray){

    frc.delegate = nil;
    frc = nil;

    [frc performFetch:&error];
}

[tv1 reloadData];
[tv2 reloadData];
[tv3 reloadData];
[tv4 reloadData];
```

This is not working.. the tables are not displaying the latest data.

However, if I take out the enumeration and do it with just one of them it works?

```
fetchedResultsControllerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:__fetchedResultsController1, __fetchedResultsController2, __fetchedResultsController3, __fetchedResultsController4, nil];

__fetchedResultsController1.delegate = nil;
__fetchedResultsController1 = nil;

[__fetchedResultsController1 performFetch:&error];

[tv1 reloadData];
[tv2 reloadData];
[tv3 reloadData];
[tv4 reloadData];
```

Can anyone explain what I might be doing wrong during enumeration?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect if you set `frc = nil` inside the loop?

Comment: I'm expecting frc to be a pointer to __fetchedResultsController1 on the first loop through.. __fetchedResultsController2 on the second etc..

Comment: `frc` is not a pointer to `__fetchedResultsController1` in the loop. You have `frc == __fetchedResultsController1` in the first loop etc. Setting `frc = nil` does not set `__fetchedResultsController1` to nil!  The `[frc performFetch:&error]` in the loop does NOTHING if you set `frc` to `nil` before.

Comment: Ahh, I guess I am misunderstanding enumeration.  Could you possibly post code of how I can loop through an array and do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I assume that `__fetchedResultsController1, ...` are instance variables of `self` and you want to set them to `nil`, so that they are re-created on the next access? I don't think there is a non-ugly way to do this in a loop, and it is probably not worth for 4 items.

Comment: Thanks Martin, if you wanted to provide these comments as an answer I will accept them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[frc performFetch:&error]` in the loop has no effect because you have set `frc = nil` before.

I assume that `__fetchedResultsController1, ...` are instance variables of `self` and you want to set them to `nil`, so that they are re-created on the next access? I don't think there is a non-ugly way to do this in a loop, and it is probably not worth for 4 items.